# Simulate human click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, web-scraping

I have a small scraper where I need to click an anchor link using JavaScript. I've tried a few ways: `jQuery.click()`, `document.createEvent('MouseEvents')` etc. They all sort of worked, however they don't fully execute like a human click (they open a tab like they should but don't start a download).

The anchor tag has this attribute:

```
onclick="if (document.getElementById('ReportViewer_ctl01_ctl05_ctl00').selectedIndex == 0) return false; 
if (!ClientToolbarReportViewer_ctl01.HandleClientSideExport()) __doPostBack('ReportViewer$ctl01$ctl05$ctl01','');return false;"
```

I've also tried running to crux of this in the command line :

```
 __doPostBack('ReportViewer$ctl01$ctl05$ctl01','')
```

this also sort of works but not fully like a human click.

I can go into more detail if required however at the moment I am looking for a magic bullet which I think should exist.

Comment: Why don't you access the desired uri with `PHP cURL` (in case you're using `PHP` as server-side language)?

Comment: I think there's a deliberate security-based reason for the dissimilarity; it seems to be to prevent drive-by downloads/EULA-acceptance and so forth. Though I could be hideously, *hideously* wrong.

Comment: @yoda thanks, not using php, its a mishmash of odds and ends. This link actually submits a form to simulate a download.

Comment: @beck then how are you injecting javascript on the page? It's always usefull to mention everything that is relevant to the subject.

Comment: `this also sort of works but not fully like a human click.` - can u explain what you mean by "sort of works" ? b/c this approach should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I keep a pastebin saved of two programmatic ways to do it.  It's only ever failed me when google decided to strip the window object (and every other object) of their default functions >.>

http://pastebin.com/VMHvjRaR

```
function callClickEvent(element){
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"); 
    evt.initEvent("click", true, true); 
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

function callClickEvent2(element){
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

callClickEvent(document.getElementById("myElement"))
callClickEvent2(document.getElementById("myElement"))
```

MDN documentation:

- [`document.createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.createEvent)
- [`event.initEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initEvent)
- [`event.initMouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initMouseEvent)
- [`element.dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.dispatchEvent)

Comment: **Live demo 1:** http://jsfiddle.net/fCbMY/ (works in all current browsers; doesn't work in IE8 since IE8 doesn't implement DOM Events)

Comment: **Live demo 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/fCbMY/1/ (again, works in all current browsers; doesn't work in IE8)

Comment: @Joseph Marikle can you update the answer as now modern browsers are able to differentiate between a human click and a simulated/triggered/dispatched event.